# Can't edit an image if user doesn't have access to English language

Tags: multilingual, role-management

In the Sitecore site I'm working on (Sitecore 9.0.2 & SXA 1.7), we have two Roles

- Arabic News Role
- English News Role

Arabic News Role has access to ar language only, and English News Role has access to en language only.

Each news article has image field, and images are un-versionable by default.

The Issue:

For Arabic News Role users when they go to any News item and trying to Edit the page Save button is disabled.

[image]

Only if I gave English language access right to Arabic News Role, it works, but then it will violate the Business rule, and the user will be able to edit English News items as well.

I assume since the images are un-versionable, Sitecore won't apply the language access rights to them. But looks like it's not the case.

Comment: Have you tried uploading the images as Versioned media items?

Comment: @RichardSeal no I haven't it will break the business rules, as the content author will have to upload a different image for each language.